# Converting jQuery easing code from ul li to table

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-easing

Here I have a jQuery easing in/out feature, and I was trying to convert it from ul li to table instead, it didn't work for me.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.topnav li').find('a[href]').parent().each(function() {
        var li = $(this),
        a = li.find('a'),
        div = $('<div>' + '<\/div>');

        li.hover(function() {
        a.stop().animate({marginTop: '-135'}, 600, "easeOutBack");
      },
      function() {
        a.stop().animate({marginTop: '0'}, 500, "easeOutBack");
      })
      .append(div);
    });
  });
```

I'm wondering what changes do I have to make other than replacing my main ul class from **.topnav li** to **.topnav tr td**

I used this html before:

```
 <ul class="topnav">
    <li><a href="#">my link</a><div>hello</div></li>
 </ul>
```

then I changed it to table like this:

```
<table class="topnav">
<tr>
<td><a href="#">my link</a><div>hello</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

but so far no luck. didn't work at all. Possibly there is something missing or something is wrong in the changes...

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you want to use tables? It doesn't work at all or not good enough? Because tables don't animate very well.

Comment: ok, I want to make everything re-sizable with the browser size. I can do the auto resizing only through tables, but not sure how with un-order listed ul li. And that's why.

Comment: With `ul` (or any other element) you have to use percentages in order to make them resizable with your browser.

Comment: ok, I know I have to use %, but not sure how to do it because I never done correctly. I tried many times, but I still unable. call me a dump, but this is the start to make it happening.

Comment: ok, maybe I don't need to convert the code. I think it is possible to just wrap the ul li with a div and things should work. I will try and see how things go. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor is by default inline element, if you change its style to `display:block;` then the animation is visible.

```css
table td a {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom: 115px;
}
table td {
    height:135px;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bP9b/7/) / [another alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/8bP9b/5/)

Comment: Thanks indeed. my great wishes to you in whole your life for the great help.

Comment: Thank you. Inspected the hovered element in Page Inspector (in Firefox it can be started with `Ctrl+Shift+i`, in Chrome with `Ctrl+Shift+J`) and there the margin was increasing and increasing, only it was not visible in page layout. It's very useful tool. Have good time!

Comment: sorry to ask again, but I think there is a little issue I didn't notice at first. if you look at the code here [http://jsfiddle.net/fxdigi/ZhUx8/] this is what I mean. not both blocks should go up at the same time, but only one so the other one shows up when the 1st one jumps...

Comment: great, but still not the same as this one http://jsfiddle.net/fxdigi/ZhUx8/. it suppose to flip when other one goes up... any idea how to do that?

Comment: you are amazing as usual. Thanks big times, mate. That was the exact answer I'm looking for. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

here's a function to convert UL to TABLE (somehow):

```
function ul2table(ul){
    var tbl = $('<table class="topnav"/>');
    ul.find('li').each(function(){
        tbl.append($('<tr/>').append($('<td/>').html($(this).html())));
    });
    ul.replaceWith(tbl);
}
```

and usage:

```
  ul2table($('ul.topnav'));
```